# How to replace space, empty, N/A, na and NA with NaN in csv using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have this code which replaces all spaces/gaps within my data structure with NaN:

`replace_spaces = data.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`

How would I update that to make it so converts all:
space, empty, N/A, na and NA type values into NaN for consistency ?

And how would I return the location of these empty strings? (I've been googling for hours couldn't find solution)

Comment: I think it would be better to check if the value is the numerical type you expect and replace any which are not with NaN .

Comment: Since you tagged this question with `pandas`, If you're using pandas, you might want to take a look at the `na_values` argument of `read_csv`, you might be able to take care of it all when you read in your data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sacuL :) I done this

````
data = pd.read_csv(file,keep_default_na=False, na_values=missing_values) ```
````

And it's work :D